# htaccess url rewriting guidance

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having problems with links showing up with my site listed twice, for example, `www.example.com/example.com/index.php?etc....` when it should simply be `www.example.com/index.php?etc....`

My links are relative and shown as: `/index.php?etc...`

I have searched through my pages' links and do not see how these incorrect links are being generated since they are not in the pages themselves as best as I can tell.

So ... I was thinking of having an .htaccess rule that renamed `www.example.com/example.com/` to `www.example.com/`

My current rename rules are:

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/img/favicon\.ico [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} favicon\.ico [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/img/favicon.ico [R=301,L] 

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

To add the new rule: (**UPDATED**)

```
    #remove double domain name - put this directly after RewriteBase
    RewriteRule ^(.*)example.com/example.com(.*)$ $1example.com$2 [R=301]
```

My questions:

- The new rule doesn't work. What is not correct? I've tested it with preg_replace and it works but in htaccess it is not renaming.
- I know I need to remove the [L,R=301] in the previous RewriteRule so that it can get to the last line. Is there a better way to use [L,R=301] so I don't get endless loops?
- Lastly, I know this is a band-aid and it would be better to find the problem. Any ideas why I might be having this problem to begin with?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: _“Any ideas why I might be having this problem to begin with?”_ – most likely because you used wrong URLs somewhere. You probably meant to use _absolute_ URLs, including the protocol (`http://` or `https://`), but left out the protocol part – and something like `href="example.com/foo"` is just a _relative_ URL, that refers to a _directory_ named `example.com` and a file `foo` in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the rewrite. Still working on the why the problem to begin with...

What I learned is that with the REQUEST_URI, to leave off matching for the Host name in the condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/example.com(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) %1%2 [L,R=301]
```